# A Python function which generates and returns a dictionary for numbers between 1 to n where n is input

Tags: python

Write a Python function which generates and returns a dictionary where the keys are numbers between 1 and n (both inclusive) and the values are square of keys.
My answer is

```
#PF-Prac-9
def generate_dict(number):
    d=dict()
    for i in range(1,number+1):
        d.__setitem__(i,i*i)



    return d
```

can it be more optimal?

Comment: This exercise is no convincing use case for a dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use dictionary comprehension

```
def generate_dict(number):
    return {i:i**2 for i in range(1,number+1)}

print(generate_dict(5))
{1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
def generate_dict(number):
    d= {}
    for i in range(1,number+1):
        d[i] = i ** 2
    return d
print(generate_dict(10))
```

Output

```
{1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64, 9: 81, 10: 100}
```

This will return you a dictionary where the keys are numbers between 1 and n and the values are square of the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
def generate_dict(number):
    return dict([(i,i**2) for i in range(1,number+1)])

generate_dict(5)
```

output is

```
{1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25}
```

Comment: Functionally identical to @AMH solution, but less nice.